# basic OSC tutorial in C++? what library to use?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, osc

I would like to learn how to write the simplest server/client C++ command line application for sending a few lines of data from one application to the other in real-time, using OSC (Open Sound Control). I would like to make it work in localhost mode or over the network, but I think in OSC its just the question of the IP address specified.

I don't know anything about OSC, and the official page seems a bit ambiguous. On this page it says:

> CNMAT's open-source library for
>   constructing OSC packets: This is all
>   you need if you want your application
>   to be able to format OSC packets for
>   sending over the network.
>   http://archive.cnmat.berkeley.edu/OpenSoundControl/src/libOSC/

But that is just a few files from 2003-2004, definitely not something I would plan on using for learning OSC. Then it introduces [OSC Control Kit](http://archive.cnmat.berkeley.edu/OpenSoundControl/Kit/), but on another page it says that its out-dated and strongly suggest against using the control kit.

Maybe this is the best page: http://opensoundcontrol.org/guide-osc-libraries which lists libraries and gives some opinion on them, but I still don't know which library I should choose out of the 4.

**What I would like to learn/use is a simple, cross-platform widely supported library that I could use in Visual C++ 2010 for building command line applications.** What do you suggest? Can you write or link a tutorial using that library?

Comment: Check this short working video tutorial on how to establish osc protocol : https://youtu.be/h-c89HPcgHU

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We are using oscpack as a cross plattform osc library.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/oscpack/downloads

we are using it with Linux, Windows and MacOSX and are quite happy. It's simple to use
and works well.

Answer (score 4):

The OSC Library is written in C++, but an ActiveX control is included that can be used from most Windows development environments (such as VisualBasic). Also, the OSC Library has been ported to Delphi

http://www.hammersound.net/osc.html